# Error: Unable to write parameter catalog: SASUSER.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST

Tags: sas

I am running a SAS job on Server and getting this error:
Unable to write parameter catalog: SASUSER.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST
Any help/comments will be appreciated

Comment: Google finds http://support.sas.com/kb/33/805.html

Answer (score 2):

This is symptom of not having write access to the SASUSER library. Usually it is generated by PROC IMPORT which seems incapable of checking the RSASUSER setting and understanding that the SASUSER library is not writable.  It should not cause any trouble.